# Condition With Sub Query Amount Eloquent Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have two table consist of users and posts. I want to get all user who hasn't created any post and has post less than 5 posts. I have created model with standard hasMany and belongsTo relation.

I have tried this eloquent:

```php
User::whereDoesntHave('posts', function($query){
    $query->where($query->count(),'<',5);
})->get();
```

After executing that query the error shows:

```php
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'users.id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `posts` where `users`.`id` = `posts`.`user_id`)
```

How to solve this?

Comment: This will return the users with five or more posts. So it will exclude users that do not have any posts, or have less than five posts. Change it to: `User::has('posts', '>=', 5)->get()`

Comment: @N69S As I know whereHas will return data that have sub data only, if it doesn't have data will not be returned (like right join), what I want is like left join with condition on amount of data on right side, or doesn't have data at all.

Comment: @EricLandheer The eloquent still return error. Please see the error on my question.

Comment: I added the code in the answer

Comment: I misread your question. You want 5 or less. See the answer of @N69S for the correct solution.

Comment: Did the answer fix your issue ? if so close your question by accepting the answer or the dupplicate state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `has()` method to get the users with less than 5 posts.

```
User::has('posts', '<', 5)->get()
```

It is that simple.

Here is a working example https://implode.io/azT0aD